# Use a different row as labels in pandas after read

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use the third row as the labels for a dataframe, but keep the first two rows for other uses. How can you change the labels on an existing dataframe to an existing row?

So basically this dataframe

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
5 7 8 9
a b c d
6 4 2 1
```

becomes

```
a b c d
6 4 2 1
```

And I cannot just set the headers when the file is read in because I need the first two rows and labels for some processing

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keep the first two rows for other uses".  Your result is a one-row DataFrame.  What happened to the other two rows?

Comment: It is loaded into a separate dataframe via`metaData = data[:2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be just to take a slice and then overwrite the columns:

```
In [71]:

df1 = df.loc[3:]
df1.columns = df.loc[2].values
df1
Out[71]:
   a  b  c  d
3  6  4  2  1
```

You can then assign back to `df` a slice of the rows of interest:

```
In [73]:

df = df[:2]
df
Out[73]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

First copy the first two rows into a new DataFrame.  Then rename the columns using the data contained in the second row.  Finally, delete the first three rows of data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '1', 1: '5', 2: 'a', 3: '6'},
                   'B': {0: '2', 1: '7', 2: 'b', 3: '4'},
                   'C': {0: '3', 1: '8', 2: 'c', 3: '2'},
                   'D': {0: '4', 1: '9', 2: 'd', 3: '1'}})

df2 = df.loc[:1, :].copy()
df.columns = [c for c in df.loc[2, :]]
df.drop(df.index[:3], inplace=True)

>>> df
   a  b  c  d
3  6  4  2  1

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  7  8  9
```